# /etc/cron.daily/locate has blank line. File is readonly can't edit

Tags: ubuntu, cron.daily

I get this output every day.

```
/etc/cron.daily/locate:
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.daily/locate: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/locate exited with return code 1
```

File contents with a blank beginning line:

```
#!/bin/sh

exit 0
```

This file is readonly even for root user. I can't edit, mv, rm, chmod, etc...

Ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `lsattr /etc/cron.daily/locate`?

Comment: If you have a root access, you should be able to delete the file unless your /etc directory is mounted 'read-only'. Are you sure your /etc is read-write? Can you post the output of the command "mount"?